# Can spieltenors sing operetta

Tags: tenor

In opera we have spieltenors. They are good at singing comical roles.
Does this mean that they are good at singing operetta as that uses comical singing?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would imagine so.

For me, the hierarchy goes 'Opera, Operetta, Musicals', with Opera the least important.   In opera, only the singing matters.   Operetta adds acting and humour.  Musicals add a story that matters, and the singers don't have to shout.

I'm not altogether joking.

Comment: You say that in opera only the singing matters but I hear people say that spieltenors should be great actors. Please clarify.

Comment: I wasn't ALTOGETHER joking.